# R L CIRCUIT DESIGN

Tags: passive-networks

IN inductor current lag voltage by 90 if resistance and inductor is series .if laging current goes to resistor what happen .please explain about current from inductor to resistor

Comment: Huh?  *It is difficult to tell what is being asked here.*

Answer (score 2):

The resistor doesn't care about the current through the coil and its phase with voltage. The resistor is a linear component whose current is *only* determined by the voltage across it.

So it's possible that due to the phase difference the voltage across the coil is negative with respect to the current, that's when the coil is a power source when it releases its magnetic energy. Then the current in the resistor will flow in the opposite direction. That current may come from the coil or other components.